# EF 4.1 loading filtered child collections not working for many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I've been looking at [Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) and could not get it to work for a many-to-many relationship.

I created a simple model:[image: Model]

Brief description:
A `Student` can take many `Courses` and a `Course` can have many `Students`.
A `Student` can make many `Presentation`, but a `Presentation` can be made by only one `Student`.
So what we have is  a many-to-many relationship between `Students` and `Courses`, as well as a one-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Presentations`.

I've also added one `Student`, one `Course` and one `Presentation` related to each other.

Here is the code I am running:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var context = new SportsModelContainer())
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            Student student = context.Students.Find(1);

            context.
                Entry(student).
                Collection(s => s.Presentations).
                Query().
                Where(p => p.Id == 1).
                Load(); 

            context.
                Entry(student).
                Collection(s => s.Courses).
                Query().
                Where(c => c.Id == 1).
                Load();

            // Trying to run Load without calling Query() first
            context.Entry(student).Collection(s => s.Courses).Load();
        }
    }
}
```

**After loading the presentations I see that the count for `Presentations` changed from 0 to 1:** [image: After loading presentations]. **However, after doing the same with `Courses` nothing changes:** [image: After attempting to load courses]

**So I try to load the courses without calling `Query` and it works as expected:** [image: Courses loaded]

*(I removed the `Where` clause to further highlight the point - the last two loading attempts only differ by the "Query()" call)*

Now, the only difference I see is that one relationship is one-to-many while the other one is many-to-many. Is this an EF bug, or am I missing something?

And btw, I checked the SQL calls for the last two `Course`-loading attempts, and they are 100% identical, so it seems that it's EF that fails to populate the collection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I could reproduce exactly the behaviour you describe. What I got working is this:

```
context.Entry(student)
       .Collection(s => s.Courses)
       .Query()
       .Include(c => c.Students)
       .Where(c => c.Id == 1)
       .Load();
```

I don't know why we should be forced also to load the other side of the many-to-many relationship (`Include(...)`) when we only want to load one collection. For me it feels indeed like a bug unless I missed some hidden reason for this requirement which is documented somewhere or not.

**Edit**

Another result: Your original query (without Include) ...

```
context.Entry(student)
       .Collection(s => s.Courses)
       .Query()
       .Where(c => c.Id == 1)
       .Load();
```

... actually loads the courses into the `DbContext` as ...

```
var localCollection = context.Courses.Local;
```

... shows. The course with Id 1 is indeed in this collection which means: loaded into the context. But it's not in the child collection of the student object.

**Edit 2**

Perhaps it is not a bug.

First of all: We are using here two different versions of `Load`:

```
DbCollectionEntry<TEntity, TElement>.Load()
```

Intellisense says:

> Loads the collection of entities from
>   the database.  Note that entities that
>   already exist in the context are not
>   overwritten with values from the
>   database.

For the other version (extension method of `IQueryable`) ...

```
DbExtensions.Load(this IQueryable source);
```

... Intellisense says:

> Enumerates the query such that for
>   server queries such as those of
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet,
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet,
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery,
>   and others the results of the query
>   will be loaded into the associated
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext,
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext or
>   other cache on the client. This is
>   equivalent to calling ToList and then
>   throwing away the list without the
>   overhead of actually creating the
>   list.

So, in this version it is **not guaranteed that the child collection is populated**, only that the objects are loaded into the context.

The question remains: Why gets the `Presentations` collection populated but not the `Courses` collection. And I think the answer is: Because of **Relationship Span**.

Relationship Span is a feature in EF which fixes automatically relationships between objects which are in the context or which are just loaded into the context. But this doesn't happen for all types of relationships. It happens only if the multiplicity is 0 or 1 on one end.

In our example it means: When we load the `Presentations` into the context (by our filtered explicit query), EF also loads the foreign key of the `Presentation` entites to the `Student` entity - "transparently", which means, no matter if the FK is exposed as property in the model of not. This loaded FK allows EF to recognize that the loaded `Presentations` belong to the `Student` entity which is already in the context.

But this is not the case for the `Courses` collection. A course does not have a foreign key to the `Student` entity. There is the many-to-many join-table in between. So, when we load the `Courses` EF does not recognize that those courses belong to the `Student` which is in the context, and therefore doesn't fix the navigation collection in the `Student` entity.

EF does this automatic fixup only for references (not collections) for performance reasons:

> To fix relationship, EF transparently
>   rewrites the query to bring
>   relationship info for all relations
>   which has multiplicity of 0..1 or1 on
>   the other end; in other words
>   navigation properties that are entity
>   reference. If an entity has
>   relationship with multiplicity of
>   greater then 1, EF will not bring back
>   the relationship info because it could
>   be performance hit and as compared to
>   bringing a single foreign along with
>   rest of the record. Bringing
>   relationship info means retrieving all
>   the foreign keys the records has.

Quote from page 128 of [Zeeshan Hirani's in depth guide to EF](http://www.daltinkurt.com/upload/dosyalar/file/Diger/entity_framework_learning_guide.pdf).

It is based on EF 4 and ObjectContext but I think this is still valid in EF 4.1 as DbContext is mainly a wrapper around ObjectContext.

Unfortunately rather complex stuff to keep in mind when using `Load`.

**And another Edit**

So, what can we do when we want to explicitely load one filtered side of a many-to-many relationship? Perhaps only this:

```
student.Courses = context.Entry(student)
       .Collection(s => s.Courses)
       .Query()
       .Where(c => c.Id == 1)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, interesting find. This produces a lot more SQL code though - basically does a new select for students with all the joins (while the version without `Include` just used the `Courses` and the mapping table to fetch only the necessary data). So it's not exactly an equivalent, but seems like a functional workaround.

Comment: In response to your edit: So the if we compare `context.Entry(...).Collections(...).Load()` and `context.Entry(...).Collections(...).Query().Load()` - the SQL is the same, the results are loaded into the context, but using `Query()` somehow makes EF "forget" to populate the collection of the `Student` object... Definitely seems like a bug to me...

Comment: @Yakimych: Perhaps I found the explanation, see my Edit2.

Comment: @Slauma - that's some impressive digging, I must admit ;) It seems to be the most plausible explanation as to what is happening. But even if you are right, and it's not a bug - this is definitely a not-so-well-thought-through design. I mean, `Load` does not return anything and one rarely would use `Load` to just load some data into the context in order to fetch it from there later on. I would rather write a normal query and get the same results into a list for further use. So as I see it, the only point of calling `Load` would be populating a collection of an already fetched object.

Comment: So as a developer using EF, I would definitely expect the collection to be populated when I call `Load`, no matter whether it's a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, and the fixup behavior should not really concern me. But the information you've digged up is really impressive and I certainly got a new dose of EF innerworkings today ;) Unless someone comes up with a better explanation soon (which I really doubt), your answer is getting accepted. And +1 from me, of course! ;)

Comment: @Yakimych: I agree. To work with `Load` on either one-to-many or many-to-many relationships it seems to be necessary to understand and consider internal EF implementation details which doesn't feel good. Calling filtered `Load` on a many-to-many relationship seems only to create "dangling" references in the context. I also don't see a scenario where I would want that.

Comment: @Slauma : The last edit is the definitive answer to me.

Comment: I'm using EF6.1 and still seeing this behaviour: frustrating!