# Entity Framework attach trouble in many to many update scenario

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a scenario where I wish to update a movie entity and its many to many relationship with Genres.

The navigation property `Genres` in movie contains stub `Genre` objects that only contain the `GenreID` because I want to save querying the DB for all genres.

See the code below, its fairly self explanatory. The problem is that I need to attach my "Stub" genres to the context so the EF will only modify the M:M relationship and not try to create new Genre records. This causes an error if a genre is already attached to the context from when I load the movie's current genres. It can't track multiple objects with the same keys.

How should this be handled? Is there a way to check if the context is already tracking the entity, or is there a better solution to this problem?

The code is below:

```
public override void Update(Movie movie)
        {
            //Backup new genres before clearing genres from movie
            var newGenres = movie.Genres;
            movie.Genres = new List<Genre>();


            _ctx.Entry(movie).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

            //Load movie's current genres from DB and remove them
            _ctx.Entry(movie).Collection(m => m.Genres).Load();
            movie.Genres.Clear();

            //Add new genres to movie
            foreach (var genre in newGenres)
            {
                _ctx.Genres.Attach(genre); //Problem if genre already attached
                movie.Genres.Add(genre);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to avoid to attach the stubs if an entity with the same key is already attached:

```
public override void Update(Movie movie)
{
    //Backup new genres before clearing genres from movie
    var newGenres = movie.Genres;
    movie.Genres = new List<Genre>();

    _ctx.Entry(movie).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

    //Load movie's current genres from DB and remove them
    ctx.Entry(movie).Collection(m => m.Genres).Load();
    var currentGenres = movie.Genres.ToList();
    movie.Genres.Clear();

    //Add new genres to movie
    foreach (var genre in newGenres)
    {
        var currentGenre = currentGenres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == genre.Id);
        if (currentGenre != null)
            movie.Genres.Add(currentGenre);
        else
        {
            _ctx.Genres.Attach(genre);
            movie.Genres.Add(genre);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code would not mark the existing genres on the movie (prior to the update) as needing to be deleted because they're not loaded into the movie's navigation property (Genres). Also I don't think you can call ToList() after the Collection() or am I missing something?

Comment: @C.J.: Deleting should be handled by `movie.Genres.Clear();`. It deletes the reference between movie and genre, not the genre itself of course. (I think you didn't want to delete the genre, did you?) `ToList` should work, it will populate the `movie.Genres` collection as well. Basically: `Load()` = `ToList()` without returning a reference to the collection. I just wanted to hold the reference for the later foreach loop.

Comment: @C.J.: Sorry, using the `ToList()` directly on the collection was wrong indeed. There must be a `Query()` in between. I've corrected that.

Comment: @C.J.: I changed the code a second time. We must indeed use `Load` here. For one-to-many relationships using `Query().ToList()` would work and also populate the genre collection of the movie (a feature called "relationship span"). But for many-to-many relationships it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6142283/270591. I've tested the code above now and it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, now that looks like it will solve the problem. The update method turned out to be a bit more code than I was shooting for, but I think this may be the best way. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I love the synchronicity of SO sometimes - the exact problem I've just today had was asked and answered just 5 days previously! :)