# Update hierarchy model in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two model classes:

Request:

```
public partial class Request
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public long DeviceId { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinalized { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

Device:

```
public partial class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
        this.Requests = new List<Request>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

I have to update the models I use this method

```
    public void Update(RequestViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var entity = _mappingEngine.Map<Request>(viewModel);
        _requests.Attach(entity);
        _uow.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

but only `Request` model is updated after calling the `Update` method. I want to update both models. Please help me.

Comment: Try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522596/entity-framework-attach-trouble-in-many-to-many-update-scenario

Answer (score 0):

Attaching an entity to a `DbContext`, mark the attached entity and all its dependencies (i.e. associated entities) `UnChanged`. So its you who must tell `EF` what entities are new and what entities were modified.